# Gap between nested container view controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Have a `UITabbarController` and two `UINavigationViewController` nested in. `UINavigationViewController`s have toolbars both, but toolbars are not laying at the bottom, but 44px upper. Why?

[image]

[image]

Toolbars added programmatically:

```
UIBarButtonItem *update = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[PfbUtility imageFromConfigIfExist:@"reload"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(eah)];
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: update, nil];
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

Comment: How are you adding these toolbars?

Comment: programmatically

Comment: In Storyboard, try attaching the bottom side of the splitview **below** the tabBar, not on top of it (if you haven't already)?

Comment: Oh, looks like it's like that already.. Does this happen on iOS 11 only, or all versions?

Comment: Thanks, yes, attaching it **below** works. Though it is nasty fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the bottom side of the splitview to the bottom edge of the screen/view (below the tabBar), not to the top of the tabBar. The application understands that it is below a tabBar and will automatically offset/inset content based on this. This is not a 'nasty fix', it is the intended way to do it. When doing this, you also have the option of using translucent navigation and tabBars.